# Merging Videos And Video Player Together

Tags: windows, video, merge

I'm trying to find something to help me merge a video file with its software so the client can only view the data/video from this software without copying the files to his/her computer.

I have seen a lot of files like .cab files or other extensions like DVRs

How can I do the same to view the files that are compressed into a file .cab .name and when a client needs to view the file they need  to use my software to open the videos without copying the files into the client computers

Comment: You're writing your one software to do this? How does this differ from streaming?

Comment: music2myear i have videos that runs on genetec video player. i need to hide these videos in a cab file or dat file like DVR softwares i dont want client to copy the videos to thr local computer i need them only when clicking on the generated exe to play the videos through genetec only and NOT to copy them to the local computer

Comment: What do you mean when you wish them not to be copied to the local computer? Do you wish to prevent screen recording? If you're limited to a specific player, then you're limited to the features of that player.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar question [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/785954/is-it-possible-to-stream-live-audio-video-safe-from-duplication-copying/) and simply brought the answer on over to this question:

> You can output the file from a call to a server-side script, e.g. `http://example.com/getfile.php?file=test.m4a`, and after the file has been sent completely, delete it from the server, or make it inaccessible (e.g. storing the information about access in a  database). This can be done with any reasonably good server-side programming language.

> For live streaming, you could – again, server-side – set up a solution where a video/audio player is embedded in the webpage, and it requests the file (or the stream endpoint) using a custom token that is only generated once (when the page loads), and only valid for one client request. For example, the player in the website would request `http://example.com/getfile.php?file=test.m4a&token=abcdef`, and once that has been requested, the token is marked as invalid on the server. Any future request with this token would fail, and the user can only get a token once (e.g. by checking via mandatory user login).

> Then again, there's this thing about DRM: It doesn't work. If people can listen to your file or play the video, nothing stops them from recording their sound card output or doing a screen capture.

[SOURCE](https://superuser.com/questions/785954/is-it-possible-to-stream-live-audio-video-safe-from-duplication-copying/785955#785955%20answered%20by%20user) answer from user [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)

Comment: Kalamalka Kid thank you for your post but this didnt answer my question. the files are located on local computer / DVD not online

Comment: You should paste answer in blockquote if you have copied it from the web. Otherwise the answer may become invalid and it may lead you to timed suspension.

Comment: @WasifHasan oops, sorry for that, and thanks for the edit. I didnt know about this policy, and thought that posting the source and author name, as well as link to original question was sufficient.